# Merging several factor variables

Tags: r, merge, r-factor

This is a follow-up to an earlier question I had: [Combining Survey Items in R/ Recoding NAs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658538/combining-survey-items-in-r-recoding-nas)

I have a data-frame that has multiple factor-variables that  I want to combine into one variable.

```
ID      REGIONA REGIONB REGIONC
A        North     NA      NA
A        South     NA      NA
B        NA      East      NA
B        NA      West      NA
C        NA        NA     North
C        NA        NA     East
```

I want the combined data frame to look like this.

```
ID      REGION
A        North    
A        South     
B        East      
B        West      
C        North       
C        East
```

Using the technique in the previous post   `within(df, x3 <- ifelse(is.na(x1), x2, x1))`works for numbers, but does not seem to handle the factors well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `levels`.  for more info look at the help file for `?factor`.

```
within(df, x3 <- ifelse(is.na(x1), levels(x2)[x2], levels(x1)[x1]))
```

Or with your example:

```
within(df, x3 <- ifelse(!is.na(REGIONA), 
                        levels(REGIONA)[REGIONA], 
                        ifelse(!is.na(REGIONB), 
                               levels(REGIONB)[REGIONB],
                               levels(REGIONC)[REGIONC])))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 # Reproducing your data frame:

 DF <- data.frame(ID=rep(c('A', 'B', 'C'), each=2), 
                  REGIONA=c('North', 'South', rep('NA', 4) ),
                  REGIONB=c('NA', 'NA', 'East', 'West', 'NA', 'NA'),
                  REGIONC=c(rep('NA', 4), 'North', 'East'))

 # Your data frame contains levels, it is necessary that 'NA' becomes NA, so:

 DF[DF=='NA'] <- NA

 # Removing NA's
 ind <- apply(DF, 2, is.na)
 new <- data.frame(matrix(DF[!ind], nrow(DF)))
 colnames(new) <- c('ID', 'REGION')
 new
  ID REGION
1  A  North
2  A  South
3  B   East
4  B   West
5  C  North
6  C   East
```

Comment: I don't think you need `apply`. `data.frame(matrix(DF[!is.na(DF)], nrow(DF)))` should suffice.